# WPF VB.Net ProgressBar updating in an Async Method

Tags: wpf, vb.net, asynchronous, progress-bar

I've seen a few other posts about this but I seem to be confused since I've seen it done several ways and haven't gotten it correct any of the ways, so I thought I would ask specifically for my case so I can learn what I am doing wrong.  After learning and switching to C# for most of my programming, VB.net seems so clunky in its syntax with a lot of things, especially lambda and "on-the-fly" functions.

I have a long running task for a football game I am working on where it generates players. Its an async method utilizing the Task.Factory.StartNew method.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
  Private Sub CreateDraft_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles CreateDraft.Click

        TimeIt(Sub() ReallyGenNewPlayers())

  End Sub

       'Uses a stopwatch to time how long it takes and sends to console.
        Private Sub TimeIt(MyAction As Action)
            Dim SW As New Stopwatch
            SW.Start()
            MyAction()
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Time Generating Players: {SW.Elapsed} seconds")
            SW.Stop()
        End Sub


        Private Async Sub GenNewPlayersASync()
            Dim myvalue = 0
            'Generate the Players on an Async Thread
            Dim x As Integer

            For i As Integer = 1 To NumPlayers
                x = i 'avoids issue with using the iteration variable inside the delegate
                CollegePlayers.GenDraftPlayers(i, MyDraft, DraftDT, DraftClass, PosCount)

                'Prog_ValueChanged(DBNull.Value, New RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double))

                'Calls a delegate to update the progress bar to avoid having the variable locked by the background thread

                Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                               worker.ReportProgress((x / NumPlayers) * 100)
                               End Sub)
            Next i

        End Sub

        'Creates a task to run the player generation code and wait til its finished
        Private Sub ReallyGenNewPlayers()
            Dim mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() GenNewPlayersASync())
            Task.WaitAll(mytask)
        End Sub
```

So here is what I would like to do: 
I have a progressbar I created in XAML that has a Progress_Changed Event.  This is what I have for it so far based on another post, but the issue is when I have to call the function inside GenNewPlayersAsync() where it wants a RoutedPropertyChangeEventArgs as a double which I'm not exactly sure what to do...I tried creating one using .New(old value, new value) but that didn't work either and threw an error.

```
Public Async Sub Prog_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double))
        Dim progress = New Progress(Of Integer)(Function(percent)
                                                    Prog.Value = e.NewValue
                                                    Return Prog.Value
                                                End Function)
        Await Task.Run(Sub() DoProcessing(progress))

    End Sub

    Public Sub DoProcessing(progress As IProgress(Of Integer))
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i <> 100
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            ' CPU-bound work
            If progress IsNot Nothing Then
                progress.Report(i)
            End If
        End While
    End Sub
```

I would like for the progressbar to be bound to an INotifyChanged Property and update itself automatically when the value gets changed.  None of it seems to be working.  The UI is still unresponsive and when I set different parts to ASync, I start getting Exceptions where it appears certain parts of the generation algorithm aren't working as they are returning null...very confused with all of this, and I am sure the answer is probably pretty simple...

If you guys could give several examples of different ways to get this to work so I can learn different methods and maybe state the pros and cons of the method I would greatly appreciate it...

Comment: I just noticed no one has responded to this question of yours. May I ask if you could show the `ProgressChanged` event that gets raised by `worker.ReportProgress((x / NumPlayers) * 100)`?

Comment: Actually got it working by using Async and Await and then using Task.Run and Delegate.BeginInvoke

Comment: Well that's good to hear! As a side note you generally wouldn't need all the workarounds you attempted above. The most simple thing (which should work, but I'm a WinForms guy so I'm not 100% sure) you could do is something like this: `Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value += 1)`

Comment: Yeah I realized it after I started reading that Background worker is pretty much deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code because Tasks were made to encapsulate all of their functionality and a lot more, while being much simpler to boot...  I had to use BeginInvoke because its asynchronous while Invoke is Synchronous and locked up everything...

Comment: Be careful when using `BeginInvoke` though. I don't know how WPF works, but for WinForms it has been said to be okay to use it on _controls_. But otherwise you are generally required to also call `EndInvoke` (which is synchronous) to end the async operation and throw any exceptions. By not doing so you will most likely get memory and thread leaks.